# Disable Google Analytics or Flurry reporting on 3G in Android application

Tags: android, google-analytics, flurry

We need to implement a statistic service in our Android application and we don't want it to take user's 3G traffic. 
Is there is a way to set up Google Analytics or Flurry reporting to let it send reports only when phone is connected via Wi-fi?

If they don't allow to set it up, which statistic service would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's impossible. Guys from Flurry told me that Flurry SDK will start sending data once a call is make to onStart() regardless of connection type. But the amount of data sending it not very large and shouldn't cause a huge spike in data usage

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Did you get any feedback on Google Analytics or just Flurry?